# Can't build app in Visual Studio 2017 while using Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, gradle

I'm trying to get a .apk for my project. I'm using Apache Cordova in Visual Studio 2017. When i tried to build my solution it always give some errors. I installed Gradle, Java Developer Kit. I have latest version of Cordova.
 Project is very simple. I used some scripts and html elements. But always I get errors. I just tried to combine default files with mine to see if I mistakly do something wrong. It doesn't changed. I even tried to build default project.
Here is what I get when i simply combine files without much changes. I always get that 31 errors. Here is my Error List:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M   Colors      1   
Error       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip   Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)    Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)    Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)    Colors      1   
Error       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip   Colors      1   
Error        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)  Colors      1   
Error        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)   Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)    Colors      1   
Error        ... 3 more Colors      1   
Error       Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:   Colors      1   
Error       Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M   Colors      1   
Error       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip   Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:78)    Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)    Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)    Colors      1   
Error       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip   Colors      1   
Error        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)  Colors      1   
Error        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)   Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)  Colors      1   
Error        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)    Colors      1   
Error        ... 3 more Colors      1
```

I'm just new to all these things. Did i missed something? Should I install some extra plugins or tools?

Answer (score 6):

There are some simple steps to fix the error.

**1)** find and open `platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js` file with text editor.
Find the line

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';
```

then change `http` to `https` in this line as follows:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip';
```

then save the file.

**2)** Check installed jdk versions and install **jdk 1.8** if not installed.

Then if the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is anything but `1.8` open `tools->options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides` in Visual Studio, check the `JAVA_HOME` checkbox and select the java 1.8 folder like follows:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241`

then run build it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because Cordova wants to update your gradle package but the url is invalid.

you can try accessing the URL in the error message:
http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
as you can see that link is forbidden by that site.
that is because that site has to use https,
so you can use SSL and try https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
That should work!!!

So how can I resolve this issue?

**solution 1** : add a system environment variable

```
    CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.13-all.zip
```

here is a tutorial I found: https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/

**solution 2**: Update the Gradle package for Cordova manually

here is a useful tutorial I found: https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/

I hope this helps you !!!

Comment: I didn't get it. Why Cordova trying to downgrade? I have the latest version (v6.1.1) of Gradle. I downloaded the Binary-only thing. I will try downloading complete package. Maybe that's the problem. `Gradle 6.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-01-24 22:30:24 UTC
Revision:     a8c3750babb99d1894378073499d6716a1a1fa5d

Kotlin:       1.3.61
Groovy:       2.5.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019
JVM:          13.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 13.0.2+8)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64`

Comment: I tried to add variable. It tried to download that file but couldn't manage it. I replaced the Gradle "binary-only" files with "complete". Then it didn't show that error anymore but now I have 45 errors.